# POST not being recoreded

Tags: php

I resently made a website and was trying to get someones carrier in php. Here is what I have so far

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
    echo $carrier;
}
}
?>


<div class="container text-center">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">


                <h1 class="likert-header">Optional phone number</h1>
                  <h3>if your phone carrier is not in the dropdown then requist it with a support ticket</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="carrier" id="carrier">
                            <option value="abc">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Verizon">Verizon</option>
                            <option value="ATT">AT&T </option>
                            <option value="Sprint">Sprint </option>
                            <option value="TMobile">T-Mobile </option>
                            </div>
                        </select>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It wont print anything even when I select i.e. Verizon. I have used this same code before and dont know why it doesnt work. here is the site tech.rekanoh.com/test.php

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['username']` is valid?

Comment: First check you getting somehing in $_SESSION OR $_POST array. like this : print_r($_SESSION); OR print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 2):

You'll need `session_start()` at the top of the file.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('includes/config.php');
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
    echo $carrier;
}
}
?>
```

More information on `session_start()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php.

Comment: Unless `includes/config.php` has `session_start()` before it prints anything out, this should be the solution @MathMXC

Comment: @MathMXC Can you post your `config.php` code? Also, is `$_SESSION['username']` set? Try echoing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your guys waste of time. I forgot an else statement at the end of the code if I was not logged in. I added it and immediately got kicked out. The code was not running because $user was not set.